# Entity Framework do not update Amazon RDS SQL database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, code-first, asp.net-web-api

I have a project with a DomainClasses C# library, a DataAccess C# library that used the Domian classes and finally a WebAPI that use the DataLayer. Also, I have an Amazon SQL RDS database.

With my context created in on of my controllers the database is not creating the tables related to my domain classes and if I use Console Manager and I Enable-Migrations on the Web API it showed me that the "No context type was found in the assembly 'WebApi'"

I have on the web config of my API the connection to AWS RDS db and I also named it the same name of my context in the datalayer. I am new on EF.

Every time that I run my application I was expecting that the databse has the tables but nothing happens there.

Thank you

This part of my code

Domain Classes:

```
public class SensorSession
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public virtual UserTest User { get; set; }
        public virtual List<SensorTest> SensorsCollected { get; set; } 
    }
  public class SensorTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HeartRate { get; set; }
        public int SkinConductivity { get; set; }
        public int Temperature {get; set;}
        public int Movement { get; set; }
        public int IndoorPositioning { get; set; }
        public DateTime CollectedDateTime { get; set; }
    }
   public class UserTest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    }
```

DATA LAYER

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    public class TestDataContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SensorSession> SensorSessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SensorTest> SensorTests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserTest> UserTests { get; set; }
    }
}


public class TestDataInitialializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TestDataContext context)
        {

            var testUser = new UserTest
            {
                Name = "Denis",
                ProviderId = 1
            };
            var sensorTest = new SensorTest
            {
                CollectedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                HeartRate = 74,
                IndoorPositioning = 1,
                Movement = 2,
                SkinConductivity = 3,
                Temperature = 30
            };

            new List<SensorSession>
            {   new SensorSession
                {
                    StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                    EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                    User = testUser,
                    SensorsCollected = new List<SensorTest> { sensorTest }
                }
            }.ForEach(b => context.SensorSessions.Add(b));

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

WEB API

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDataContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="my aws rds link"/>
     </connectionStrings>
```

Global as

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new TestDataInitialializer());
...
}
```

Comment: the problem is not from DataLayer the message seems related to ApiController class (eg. Get, Put, Post parameters object can't be serialized)

Comment: Yes the problem it is on the APIController. I am not doing anything yet on the methods related to the controller() eg. Get, Post, etc.). What I am doing there is creating my db; private TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext(); before use it on those methods. However the schema of the database on AWS RDS is not being update and my database remains without tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization won't happen until you do something to interact with the database from the context.. A query, a savechanges or even one of the direct executesql commands. There is also a command Database.Initialize that you can use to force it by passing in the force parameter of true.

Comment: Thank you Julie. When you say that there is a Database.Initialize where can I find it and where should I use it. I set an Initializer in the Global.asx.cs on the Application_Start() the Database.SetInitializer but when I am trying to the Database.Initialize I am having "Unknown type Initialize of System.Data.Entity.Database"

Comment: I added on the controller some CRUD operation and my schema was update. Thank you. However, if you can let me know where I can use Initialize so I can clean my code.

Comment: great to hear that you got the initialize to happen explicilty via an operation. Don't initialize in the global.asax. It's not something you want to happen every time. Just something to do maybe from an integration test or something when you are just at the point where you have some of the data layer written but not the triggers to act on the data layer. And it is definitely in System.Data.Entity.Database. But it's static, so don't try to instantiate the Database class.  There's an example of using it in this blog post: http://juliel.me/U6ZCNG  hope that helps!